# How to solve flickering WS2812?

Tags: arduino, flicker, led

I have a problem with flickering neopixel leds. I'm using a setup of 6 strips of 8xWS2812 5050 leds. I've connected these to a 5v power supply (USB charger) and an Arduino Uno running the Neopixel simple example code:

```
// NeoPixel Ring simple sketch (c) 2013 Shae Erisson
// released under the GPLv3 license to match the rest of the AdaFruit NeoPixel library

#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN            6

#define NUMPIXELS      48

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int delayval = 50; // delay for half a second

void setup() {
  // This is for Trinket 5V 16MHz, you can remove these three lines if you are not using a Trinket
#if defined (__AVR_ATtiny85__)
  if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
#endif
  // End of trinket special code

  pixels.begin(); // This initializes the NeoPixel library.
}

void loop() {
for(int i=0;i<NUMPIXELS;i++){
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(200,200,200)); // Moderately bright green color.

    pixels.show(); // This sends the updated pixel color to the hardware.

    delay(delayval); // Delay for a period of time (in milliseconds).

  }
}
```

I've connected a 500uf 10v capacitor between the 5v and the gnd. And a 470 ohm resister between the arduino and the datapin.

I've noticed that the leds also flicker when the leds are on and the datapin is disconnected. The flickering is subtle, but annoying.
I've also tried an alternative power supply. For this I used a adjustable lab power supply. But the same problem persists.

I have to use these leds for a project that I need to finish tomorrow. (I know i should have done this earlier) Is there anyone who could offer me some help? I could really use some.

EDIT: The flickering had to do with the quality of the leds. These weren't real neopixels, instead I received some bad fake ones.

Comment: I don't think this is programming question. Suggest you to move it to arduino.stackexchange.com or electronics.stackexchange.com